# PHP PCRE syntax

Tags: php, pcre

I'm a newbie with PCRE in PHP. I'm trying to make a very basic shortcode function that could  make something with a format like this one: `{somealphanumericthing}`

In essence I need a `preg_match_all()` that could find in my post these type of occurrences. I tried something like this:

```
$shortcode = preg_match_all('/^\b\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\}\b)$/', $body, $found);
    var_dump($shortcode);
    if($shortcode==1) {
        for($i=0;$i<count($found);$i++) {
            print_r($found);
                        //do something nice
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately it's not working: I get int 0 to the test string {test}

Comment: Tell us what's *not working* … Is the `var_dump()` *dumping* anything?

Comment: I get int 0 to the test string {test}

Comment: do not count elements in array on each iteration, use `for($i=0,$c=count($found);$i<$c;++$i)`

Comment: If this is going to be replaced with something in your code you are probably looking for preg_replace or preg_replace_callback

Comment: People are really overusing this **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved** close.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - I tend to agree. Basically it is RTFM 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things about the regular expression:

- You don't need your line anchors since you are searching in a larger string.
- There's not need to capture the closing `}`
- Optimization, use the character class `\w`

Condensed:

```
/\b\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\}\b/
```